# Is every abstraction capital in the abstract?

Tags: marx, abstract

I'm unsure how Marx uses 'abstraction' and 'concrete', beyond the fact that exchange value is an abstraction from concrete use value. Is every abstraction from the capitalist mode of production - i.e. every abstraction from the world we inhabit - capital in the abstract, part of the becoming of capital, capital in general?

I think that's the same as asking whether concrete things (e.g. use values) are the only things that do not exist to make money.

Answer (score 0):

In philosophy, the category abstract means to consider something without any unimportant characteristics. Concrete is the opposite where we are talking about the thing in all of its context.

Here's a great video explaining abstraction using math: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQYOpD7tv30&pp=ygUQbWF0aCBhYnN0cmFjdGlvbg%3D%3D

To give my example we can think about a mathematical addition: Imagine we have two chickens, one laid 3 eggs and the other 2 eggs. To know how many eggs we have in total we first abstract the unnecessary facts: the facts these are eggs from different chickens. As of now, this are not "3 eggs from chicken A" and "2 eggs from chicken B". Now in the abstract these are just numbers: 3 and 2. We add them in abstraction 3+2=5. Now we go back to the concrete: "We have 5 chicken eggs."

So when Marx talks about use-value being concrete it means that we consider the concrete commodity usefulness, in context: a bible we can read, a coat we can wear or food we can eat. We are considering the commodity in it's materiality in a concrete moment.

On the other hand, exchange-value being abstract means that in order for my concrete bible and your concrete coat to be exchangeable we need to consider them without their use-value aspcet (abstractly): It does not matter if my commodity is a bible and your commodity is a coat, when considered for exchange they are the same: a valuable thing we can trade.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).